# Video preview window in VSE missing

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

[image: VSE in blender with preview window missing]

I've removed the preview window somehow but I have no idea how to get it back. Ive gone through the properties but I can't find a way to bring it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the three buttons in the Video Sequence Editor header to control the view mode. Either *Sequencer*, *Preview* or *Both*.

[image]

Comment: For blender 2.9, after selecting `video sequencer` type window, in the top drop down box of that video sequencer window, select `preview`.

Comment: @run_the_race Thanks for the update, that is valuable info. Rather than post it in the comments where it can be easily missed, could you post it as a new answer instead?  Or perhaps propose an edit to my answer including those details, you may even earn some reputation from it