# How do I show the video preview?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I was assembling a bunch of screen recordings into a single video using Blender's "Video Editing" mode (which I've done several times before) when I accidentally clicked something and made the video preview disappear:

[image]

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92914/video-preview-window-in-vse-missing):

First, you want to look for the 'window selector' icon, and click it, and choose the 'Video Sequence Editor' option:

[image]

Next, if you don't immediately see the video preview, you want to click a button on the bottom of that window that has a red-and-white checkerboard pattern, that will switch the window to be a video preview:

[image]

Finally, if the zoom is somehow messed up so that you don't see the entire image in the window, click the 'View' dropdown and choose the 'Fit preview in window' option:

[image]

And when all that's done, this is what the window should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You switched to the Graph editor from the **mode selection dropdown menu**.
Switch over to the Videoeditor from the same dropdown menu

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had tried that and saw the actual sequence editor instead of the preview, so I thought at first that wasn't the right option.  After doing some more research I realized there was a separate button I needed to click to switch it to the video preview.